# Magento 2: Any Quick Option how to Make Magento 2.2.x Website compatible with PHP 7.3 without Magento Version Upgrade?

Tags: magento2, php-7, magento-upgrade

i want to make my magento 2.2.X website compitable with php version 7.3 without upgrading the magento version of my site.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You should perform the upgrade of Magento or delay upgrade of PHP.

Compatibility with 7.3 starts with version 2.3, but I suggest an upgrade latest available version:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/release/
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Please take into consideration that Magento 2.2 is long gone dead, no support what so ever for this version, so many serious problems besides the PHP being outdated.

Answer (score 0):

> **You cannot make Magento 2.2.x compatible with PHP 7.3 because that Magento version does not support PHP 7.3. When installing Magento, all packages and third-party modules depend on the PHP version. Therefore, it is impossible to update to PHP 7.3. You can only make your custom module compatible with PHP 7.3, but this is not acceptable because everything depends on your Magento version. If you want to use PHP 7.3, first update your Magento version, and then you can get a Magento version that is compatible with PHP 7.3.**